# How to avoid refreshing the page in the else part of the code and just show a prompt without postback. Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download excel in the `if` part but in the `else` part I need to show a prompt showing empty excel but its refreshing the page after showing the prompt and it messes up the webpage and when refreshing the page again it shows the same prompt again and again.

```
Datatable dt1;
if(dt1 != null && dt1.rows.count > 1)
{
   //...
}
else
{
    //enter code here
    string str = "<script>alert(\"EMPTY EXCEL\");</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", str, false);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `Response.Write("<script>alert('Empty Excel');</script>");`

Comment: Yeah it does the same thing as the clientscript functionalities did

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: its under a button not in pageload()

Comment: Then better you add a client side click method and call the JS method

Comment: yeah thats sounds about right

Comment: go ahead and give a try :)

Comment: i have one question if i validate it from js function what should i pass in the else condtion of this method

Comment: Yes if it’s some C# variable. Flog it’s control then you can access by GetElementById

Comment: yeah its showing the prompt from javascript function but after that it refreshes the page

Comment: you need to add `return false;`